# Moodle 2.9: Storing additional information in session cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies, moodle

In my moodle courses, there are audiofiles the students can play twice (restriction of repetitions is done with jQuery). But unfortunately a simple reload of the page resets that limit. So I would like to store the count of plays in a cookie. In order to avoid the possibility a user just deletes the cookie, the best would be, I could store the information directly in the session cookie. How is that done? Or are there better ways to accomplish this job?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put in place some sort of AJAX callback to the site and then store the number of times each item has been listened to in the Moodle $SESSION global variable (e.g. $SESSION->audiolimit['some sort of identifier for the audio file']).

When the page is refreshed, you should initialise the jquery limiting javascript with the number of times each track has already been played (from the $SESSION variable).

This will, of course, only work until the user has logged out & back in again, so if you need a more permanent limit, you will need to store this somewhere in the database, instead of in $SESSION. It will also not stop users from messing around with the javascript in their browser, to defeat the limit imposed that way.